# Microsoft Excel. Piece-wise Least-Squares Fit with Solver. My excel sheet produces right answers sometimes, wrong answers other times

Tags: excel, regression

I am trying to do a non-linear regression with data I have for my research. Since it is nonlinear, I can't use Simplex LP. Instead I was doing GRG Nonlinear with upper and lower bounds on all parameters.

It is weird because Excel produces answers that are right sometimes, and other times it is wrong. I have to manually change the parameters to arbitrary numbers, run Solver again, and hope that it is right. Let me show you my excel sheet.

https://drive.google.com/a/case.edu/file/d/0Bw0aJV0lW2eTaHFRUFhobVZ4NWs/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, I am looking to two linear lines to fit the data I have. The raw data can be divided into two portions, both linear. The point which the two lines cross is the Critical Value.

The correct output with my raw data is where the Critical Value = 0.006707. The last time I ran it, which is on the excel sheet, you can see that Critical Value = 3.36E-06.

If it would help you to understand this better in context, I am measuring surface tension of various systems. The critical value is so called Critical Micelle Concentration in my field.

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel solver, I think it is falling in local optima. Restarting the solver after setting the different variables to random values may help getting out of local optima values. Before restarting the solver, record the values of the objective function and compare it with the new value found by the solver.
Alternatively, use a better solver outside Excel. There are plenty of open source solvers available on the Internet.